Modeling the relation between pairs of Non-negative Continuous or Integer Variables
Say for instance, I have two non-negative continuous or integer variables, $x$, $y$, I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications
i) $x\gt 0, y\gt 0 \implies x \lt y$
ii) $x \lt y \implies x\gt 0, y\gt 0$
iii) $x \lt y \iff x\gt 0, y\gt 0$

Assume $x \le M$ and $y \le M$, and let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant tolerance.

For i), introduce binary decision variables $u,v,w$, and impose
\begin{align}
x &\le M u \tag1\label1 \\
y &\le M v \tag2\label2 \\
u+v-1 &\le w \tag3\label3 \\
x - y + \epsilon &\le (M-0+\epsilon)(1-w) \tag4\label4
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $x>0 \implies u=1$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces $y>0 \implies v=1$.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces $(u=1 \land v=1) \implies w=1$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces $w=1 \implies x+\epsilon\le y$.

For ii), introduce binary decision variable $z$ and impose
\begin{align}
y - x &\le (M-0) z \tag5\label5 \\
x &\ge \epsilon z \tag6\label6 \\
y &\ge \epsilon z \tag7\label7
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{5} enforces $x<y \implies z=1$.
Constraint \eqref{6} enforces $z=1 \implies x \ge \epsilon$.
Constraint \eqref{7} enforces $z=1 \implies y \ge \epsilon$.

For iii), enforce both i) and ii).


If $x$ and $y$ are integer variables, you can take $\epsilon=1$ throughout.

Thank you! For the iff bidirectional implication, can I equate z and w?

Yes, for iii), $z=w$ for all feasible solutions, so you can eliminate either  variable by substitution.

Thank you for confirming it!
